# mvc 5 asp.net selectlist with where condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

this is the select list in the action controller,

```
ViewBag.UserName = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(g => g.UserName == User.Identity.GetUserName()), "UserName", "UserName");
```

which I am passing to the view :

```
 <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, "UserName", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("UserName", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

and it's not working erro:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   GetUserName(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: you cannot use a function call `User.Identity.GetUserName()` within any Linq expression. What you can do is to first get the value of `User.Identity.GetUserName()` into a variable and then use that variable in your linq expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line to:

```
string userName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
ViewBag.UserName = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(g => g.UserName == userName).ToList(), "UserName", "UserName");
```

You have to add the `ToList()` after the `Where` in order to execute the query and return the results.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetUserName(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Put the `User.Identity.GetUserName()` into a variable first and make sure it has a value, I have edtited my answer

Answer (score 3):

GetUserName can't be translated into a expression. Try it like this

```
var username = User.Identity.GetUserName();
ViewBag.UserName = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(g => g.UserName == username), "UserName", "UserName");
```

And maybe adding .ToList() like Haitham suggested.

Answer (score 2):

linq/lambda expressions do not recognize the `GetUserName` function,
you have to read it in separate variable and use that variable in linq query/lambda expression.

```
 var username = User.Identity.GetUserName();
 ViewBag.UserName = new SelectList(db.Users.Where(g => g.UserName == username), "UserName", "UserName");
```